# Powershell: Get where Outlook by default stores its data files when Outlook is in a different language?

Tags: powershell, outlook

Im trying to get the folder where Outlook by default stores its data files. I know two

.....appdata/Microsoft/Outlook

.....My Documents/Outlook Files

I can get to the top one easy but the bottom one: It is translated to whatever language Outlook is it.

Is there a way I can get it, no matter the language it is?

Answer (score 1):

```
$o=New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$ns=$o.GetNamespace("MAPI")

$ns.DefaultStore
#or
$ns.Stores |?{$_.isdatafilestore} |select -expand filepath
```